# Make a table from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, multiple-columns

I'm fairly new on Python.

I have 2 columns on a dataframe, columns are something like:

```
db = pd.read_excel(path_to_file/file.xlsx)
db = db.loc[:,['col1','col2']]

col1  col2
C     4
C     5
A     1
B     6
B     1
A     2
C     4
```

I need them to be like this:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6
A  1 1 0 0 0 0
B  1 0 0 0 0 1
C  0 0 0 2 1 0
```

so they act like rows and columns and values refer to the number of coincidences.

Comment: the data? i read it from a file

Comment: Of course, but how? Provide the code and we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your columns are called `cat` and `val`:

```
In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 'val': [4, 5, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4]})

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
  cat  val
0   C    4
1   C    5
2   A    1
3   B    6
4   B    1
5   A    2
6   C    4
```

Then you can `groupby` the table hierarchicaly, then unstack it:

```
In [28]: df.val.groupby([df.cat, df.val]).sum().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[28]: 
val  1  2  4  5  6
cat               
A    1  2  0  0  0
B    1  0  0  0  6
C    0  0  8  5  0
```

**Edit**

As IanS pointed out, 3 is missing here (thanks!). If there's a range of columns you must have, then you can use

```
r = df.val.groupby([df.cat, df.val]).sum().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)

for c in set(range(1, 7)) - set(df.val.unique()):
    r[c] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need aggreagate by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and add missing values to columns by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.reindex.html):

```
print (df)
   a  b
0  C  4
1  C  5
2  A  1
3  B  6
4  B  1
5  A  2
6  C  4

df1 = df.b.groupby([df.a, df.b])
          .size()
          .unstack()
          .reindex(columns=(range(1,df.b.max() + 1)))
          .fillna(0)
          .astype(int)

df1.index.name = None
df1.columns.name = None
print (df1)
   1  2  3  4  5  6
A  1  1  0  0  0  0
B  1  0  0  0  0  1
C  0  0  0  2  1  0
```

Instead `size` you can use `count`, [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) counts `NaN` values, [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) does not.

Comment: If need output as in your question, use `size` function.